# Android string date to dateTime conversion

Tags: java, android

sample string is: `25-11-2015 14:59`

```
String str= "25-11-2015 14:59";
```

I want to convert the str to Date. But it gives me an error. My conversion function is

```
public Date getDate(String date)
    {
        try {

            Log.v("Date","Date string: "+date);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date convertedDate = new Date();
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            return  convertedDate;

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("error","error date parse : "+e.getMessage());
            return  null;
        }
    }
```

But it showing error :

> Unparseable date: "25-11-2015 14:59" (at offset 16)

can anyone help me where is the problem

Comment: Use `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: That code works for me. I'm using Java 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format pattern should probably be: `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`. `hh` is for "Hour in am/pm (1-12)", as detailed in the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may create some generic thing and check the length ;

```
public  static Date getDate(String date){
     Date convertedDate = null;

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");

        if (date.length() == 16)            
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        else if (date.length() == 10)
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 

        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date); 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return convertedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code explanation of  [`assylias`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) by considering your requirement  :)

```
      String testDateString2 = "02-04-2014 23:37";    
      SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"); 
      Date d2 = df2.parse(testDateString2);
      System.out.println("Date : "+df2.format(d2));
```